# Iteratively read bytes from standard input in c++

Tags: c++, input, cmd

So I want to read a certain amount of bytes from standard input however my code does not read next bytes, it only reads a set amount of bytes and exits.

```
while(1) {
    char c [100];
    if( read(0,  c, 100) < 1) break;
    for(int i; i<100;i++){
       cout << (c[i]);
    }
}
```

This code only prints out the first 100 characters and then exits even though there are about 10 times more characters. I thought that the buffer keeps reading next bytes every time read is called so why does read(...) return a value less than 1 if there is more bytes to read?
How do I make it read all the bytes, 100 at a time, until it finds the end of the standard input, such that it prints out the whole input?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you have a buffer overrun. If you read in 1 byte into the array, you then write 100 out of it.

Comment: @MooingDuck, the files I need to read are huge so having too big of a buffer is not a concern.

Comment: "too big of a buffer" is not the concern. The concern is that you're printing _the wrong bytes_ after the end of the file, if the file size is not an exact multiple of 100. This is a bug.

Comment: `printf` doesn't take a char parameter: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12af26f361f9ad56. Please produce a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can see the actual bug in your code

Comment: In your code, you are limiting to 100 characters.  Replace *all* instances of 100 to 1000 or however many you really want.

Comment: I just edited the question, ```cout << c[i]``` should work

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, that's the thing, I don't know how many characters there are going to be so I can't just allocate a certain amount. My code needs to have flexibility of reading in file 100 bytes at a time, regardless of how many characters there actually are.

Comment: @DenisShevchenko what is the actual return value of `read()` when the code fails? If 0, that is EOF.  If -1, what does `errno` report? And like MooingDuck said, you are ignoring the return value in your loop. Try this: `ssize_t numBytes = read(0,  c, 100); if (numBytes < 1) { /* what is numBytes set to here??? */ break; } for(ssize_t i; i < numBytes; i++){ cout << (c[i]); }` And then you can replace the whole loop with just a single call to `cout.write(c, numBytes);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flaw in my code was a logical one. It did run over the whole file however in`for(int i; i<100; i++)` i was only incremented on first run, after that i stayed at i=99 so the rest of the reads did not actually print out because i was not running over the characters read into the buffer.
Thank you everyone who attempted to help me with this.

Comment: You still need to initialize the `i` variable in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

When reading *bytes* from a file, you should open the file as binary and use the block read and write functions:

```
const unsigned int MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS = 128u;
char c[MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS];
//...
input_file.read(&c[0], MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS);
const std::streamsize actual_bytes_read = input_file.gcount();
```

Or

```
const size_t actual_bytes_read = fread(&c[0], sizeof(c), MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS, input_file);
```

When printing, you should initialize your index variable, then print:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS; ++i)
{
    printf("%0x2 ", c[i]);
    if ((i % 16) == 15)
    {
       printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:  Reading groups (blocks) of 128 bytes**
Let's use an outer `while` statement and `uint8_t` as the byte type:

```
const unsigned int BYTES_PER_BLOCK = 128U;
std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(BYTES_PER_BLOCK);
while (input_file.read(&buffer[0], BYTES_PER_BLOCK)
{
    const std::streamsize actual_bytes_read = input_file.gcount();
    // Call your function with the block
    Process_Block_Of_Bytes(buffer, actual_bytes_read);
}
```

Comment: I know it fread would make it much easier, however I want to fix this problem using ```read()``` only and I need to read it from standard input as in ```myprogram < textfile.txt```

Comment: The `read()` function must be low level, because it is not showing up in my C++ reference.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) is a Posix system function (like `ReadFile()` on Windows), not a C++ function.